# Expression of the infinite summation result of a series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, algebraic-manipulation

The infinite sum of a series should be

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{4 n+1}}{4 n+1}$ $=\frac{1}{4} \ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}+\frac{1}{2} \arctan x-x \quad(-1<x<1)$

However,

```
Sum[x^(4*n + 1)/(4*n + 1), {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> x (-1 + Hypergeometric2F1[1/4, 1, 5/4, x^4])

How to get the result: $\frac{1}{4} \ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}+\frac{1}{2} \arctan x-x \quad$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematica v12.2   `FunctionExpand` evaluates

```
sol=Sum[x^(4*n + 1)/(4*n + 1), {n, 1, Infinity}] // FunctionExpand//Expand
(*-x + ArcTan[x]/2 + ArcTanh[x]/2*)
```

If necessary `ArcTanh[]` might be transformed too

```
sol  /. ArcTanh[x] -> (ArcTanh[x] // TrigToExp)
(*-x + ArcTan[x]/2 + 1/2 (-(1/2) Log[1 - x] + 1/2 Log[1 + x])*)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Another way is as follows. First, we differentiate the sum under consideration

```
Sum[D[t^(4*n + 1)/(4*n + 1), t], {n, 1, Infinity}]
```

> `-(t^4/(-1 + t^4))`

Now we integrate the result from `0` to `x`

```
Integrate[-(t^4/(-1 + t^4)), {t, 0, x}, Assumptions -> x > -1 && x < 1]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[-x + ArcTan[x]/2 + ArcTanh[x]/2, x >= 0]`

I leave math ground on your own.

Comment: Thank you very much!